# Spring boot 3 + Authorization Server + Validating client_id stored in DB e.g. H2 + JdbcRegisteredClientRepository

Tags: spring, spring-authorization-server, spring-boot-3

I am trying to implement Authorization server using Spring boot 3.0 + H2 database for storing client details like client_id and client_secret etc.

I am able to generate token using InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository. Method used as below:

---

```
@Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("client-id")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://localhost:8000/api")
                .scope("read")
                .scope("write")
                .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder()
                        .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(60)) 
                        .build())
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build())
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }
```

---

But now, I want to store client details in H2 database and extract the client data dynamically based on client request and accordingly send back the token post validation using "JdbcRegisteredClientRepository".

I have this code snippet, but not sure it's going to work.

---

```
@Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
      
        JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository = new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
        RegisteredClient existingClient = registeredClientRepository.findByClientId("front-client");
        if(existingClient == null){
            RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .clientId("front-client")
                    .clientSecret("{noop}123456")
                    .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                    //.authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                    .redirectUri("http://localhost:8282/api")
                    .scope("swagger.read")
                    .scope("swagger.write")
                    .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder()
                            .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(60)) // Set the desired token expiration time here
                            .build())
                    .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build())
                    .build();
            registeredClientRepository.save(registeredClient);
        }
        return registeredClientRepository;
    }
```

---

For method registeredClientRepository.findByClientId(client_id), how I can get this client id based on any request coming to Authorization server.

Can anyone please help on this by providing code snippet based on my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the client Id from incoming request in Authorization server

1. Use HttpServletRequest object from RequestContextHolder.
   ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

   HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest();
   String clientId = request.getParameter("client_id");
2. OAuth2AuthenticationToken

   OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
   String clientId = oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
3. Authorization header

   String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
   String[] parts = authorizationHeader.split(" ");
   String clientId = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(parts[1])).split(":")[0];

Comment: Thank you for answering my query.
But the mentioned statement is giving a compilation error, stating cannnot be type cast to HttpServletRequest.

HttpServletRequest request = (ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequest(); 

Can you please give a complete code snippet.

Comment: ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
  HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest(); another way to get the request details.

Comment: Can you please explain end to end flow. My doubt over here is that the method  registeredClientRepository mentioned above is defined as a bean which will be initialized during application start up. Registering the inmemory client make sense over here but if the clients are in DB, then how this client credential flow works. As the clients will be in DB and based on the request coming from a specific client needs to be intercepted and accordingly authentication and authorization will be performed. If someone has any code reference, then please mention here.